# How to list files under a clearcase view via ccrc?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

is there any way to list files under a clearcase view using the remote client cli?

Currently I'm doing mkview and an update to get the files, then list them with ls/dir command. I'm only interested in the ls/dir output NOT the files themselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This won't help you, but you have my sympathy on having to work with ClearCase. It's the most horrible excuse for a source code control system I've ever had the misfortune to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind CCRC is to access file through a snapshot view, create in the CCRC server and synchronized on your workstation.

There is no dynamic view, which would give you access to some extended pathname exploration, for a remote list of the files.
You need to define your CCRC "web" view **config spec** (for ClearCase to *know* what to select and list) *and* update/load them in your workspace in order to be able to list them.

Whatever your configuration (CCRC or not), listing files means having a config spec first.
Having a config spec means having a view.
And with CCRC, the only available view is a "web" (snapshot) view, hence the "update" ordeal.

Comment: @epzee: If the config spec doesn't change much, you could set up (or ask for) a dynamic view on the server side (where you don't use CCRC but a full ClearCase client), and use it as a source for an automatic email with the list of files in it (through a custom batch). But on the CCRC-client side, no, I am not aware of any workaround.